Does Prometheus allow changing a metric type?
We’ve Prometheus scraping data from a /metrics endpoint. The metrics are declared by the app producing them (at startup time), and displayed in Grafana.
From the Prometheus standpoint, am I allowed to change metric A from a Histogram to a Summay, without renaming it? I couldn’t find any documentation on this subject. I don’t care about data loss, and I’m not currently using buckets from the Histogram.

Before you change anything Promethesus under the hood deal with metric types.
In Prometheus, if you try to change a metric's type from a Histogram to a Summary (or vice versa) without renaming it can cause issues,  and it is never RECOMMENDED.
Solely because Prometheus enforces type consistency for metrics with the same name. Once you create a metric and it is ingested with a specific type (e.g., histogram), Prometheus expects subsequent samples of that metric to be of the same type.
It is like type enforcement in any static typed programming language
SEE DOCS BEST PRACTICES: Prometheus docs

Metric names A metric name...
...must comply with the data model for valid characters. ...should
have a (single-word) application prefix relevant to the domain the
metric belongs to.
The prefix is sometimes referred to as namespace by
client libraries. For metrics specific to an application, the prefix
is usually the application name itself. Sometimes, however, metrics
are more generic, like standardized metrics exported by client
libraries. Examples: prometheus_notifications_total (specific to the
Prometheus server) process_cpu_seconds_total (exported by many client
libraries) http_request_duration_seconds (for all HTTP requests)

Also from their docs:

Histograms and summaries are more complex metric types. Not only does
a single histogram or summary create a multitude of time series, it is
also more difficult to use these metric types correctly. This section
helps you to pick and configure the appropriate metric type for your
use case.

Consequences

Data inconsistency: It could lead to sample being rejected
It would lead to misinterpretation of data by Grafana if you use it.

Possible solution

Why create a new Summary then pass it and convert it to the extracted Histogram data into a format compatible with the Summary metric. You’ll need to decide how to aggregate or summarize the histogram data (e.g., converting bucket counts into quantiles).

Why don't you write a script using their third party and hook it to your histogram or summary you want to rename and read from there.
or connect via an api then feed it back to prometheus/grafana


SEE DOCS ON HOW TO DO THIS DOCS
see a simple code snippet, to pull those information and inject back to prometheus, I am not sure how but it should happen, But a good place to start is to look at the github of what happens under the hood
PROMETHEUS_GITHUB
from prometheus_client import Summary
s = Summary('request_latency_seconds', 'Description of summary')
s.observe(4.7)    # Observe 4.7 (seconds in this case)



Thanks. Are you talking from experience? Because nothing in the docs supports your claim.

Hi @shibel this is from experience, you can look up issues on github. I was just trying to help, and also logically although both summary and history do the same thing their metric type is different have a look at the github i sent. You can setup a docker image(promethesus) and see for yourself.
